# useEffect not firing on state update

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

I am updating some state with `useState()` in my react native component. Once I have that state set I want to save the details to the server, so I have set that up in an `useEffect()` hook. To be clear, the setting of the state IS working, and I see the value print to the screen.

However, what I'm noticing is, even though I've set `note` as a dependency in the dependency array of the `useEffect()` hook, the function never fires when the state updates. What am I missing here?

```
  const [note, setNote] = useState('');
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  useEffect(() => {
    if (note) {
      console.log('updating note...');
      dispatch(updateNote(props.client.id, note));
    }
  }, [note]);
```

FYI, I am updating the state inside a TextInput, like so (I had to use onBlur to avoid the issue of react loosing focus on the first character type because I am passing a component within `screenOptions` of a TabNavigator):

```
<TextInput
  key='note'
  style={{
    color: '#fff',
    fontSize: 16,
    width: '100%',
    textAlign: 'center',
  }}
  placeholder='Tap here to share something...'
  placeholderTextColor={styles.colors.textPlaceholder}
  maxLength={50}
  onBlur={(text) => setNote(text)}
  defaultValue={note || props?.client?.note?.value}
/>
```

As I mentioned, this has been a tricky situation because I had to get around react's loss of focus when I rely on `onChangeText()` or `onChange()`. I am passing in a `CustomHeader` - which is a function inside the parent, to a TabNavigator within `screenOptions` like so:

```
  screenOptions={{
    headerShown: true,
    headerStyle: {
      backgroundColor: Colors.primary,
      elevation: 0,
      shadowOpacity: 0,
      shadowColor: 'transparent',
      height: 170,
    },
    key: 'patient-tab',
    headerShadowVisible: false,
    tabBarStyle: { backgroundColor: Colors.primary },
    headerTintColor: Colors.light,
    headerTitle: (props) => <CustomHeader {...props} />, // Passed in here
    tabBarActiveTintColor: Colors.light,
    tabBarInactiveTintColor: Colors.lightInactive,
    tabBarActiveBackgroundColor: Colors.primary,
    tabBarInactiveBackgroundColor: Colors.primary,
  }}
```

The full code looks like this:

```
export const ClientBottomTabNavigator = (props) => {
  const [note, setNote] = useState('');
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  useEffect(() => {
    if (props.client.id && note) {
      console.log('updating note...');
      dispatch(updateNote(props.client.id, note));
    }
  }, [props.client.id, note]);

  const CustomHeader = () => {
    return (
      <View>
        <View style={{ width: '100%', flexDirection: 'row', justifyContent: 'space-between', marginBottom: 6 }}>
          <Feather
            name='chevron-left'
            size={24}
            onPress={() => props.navigation.goBack()}
            color={styles.colors.textInverse}
            style={{ justifySelf: 'flex-start', alignSelf: 'flex-start', width: '32%', marginBottom: 6 }}
          />
          <Text
            style={{
              color: '#fff',
              fontSize: 18,
              alignSelf: 'center',
              justifySelf: 'center',
              fontWeight: 'bold',
            }}
          >
            {props?.client?.firstName} {props?.client?.lastName}
          </Text>
          <Feather
            name='' // Leave this blank
            style={{ justifySelf: 'flex-end', alignSelf: 'flex-end', width: '32%' }}
          />
        </View>

        <View style={{ alignItems: 'center', marginBottom: 6 }}>
          <Text style={{ color: '#fff', fontSize: 18, marginBottom: 6 }}>
            {convertDiscipline(props?.client?.discipline)}
          </Text>
          <View>
            <TextInput
              key='note'
              style={{
                color: '#fff',
                fontSize: 16,
                width: '100%',
                textAlign: 'center',
              }}
              placeholder='Tap here to share something…’
              placeholderTextColor={styles.colors.textPlaceholder}
              maxLength={50}
              onBlur={(text) => setNote(text)}
              defaultValue={note || props?.client?.note?.value}
            />
          </View>
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  };

  const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();
  return (
    <Tab.Navigator
      screenOptions={{
        headerShown: true,
        headerStyle: {
          backgroundColor: Colors.primary,
          elevation: 0,
          shadowOpacity: 0,
          shadowColor: 'transparent',
          height: 170,
        },
        key: 'client-tab',
        headerShadowVisible: false,
        tabBarStyle: { backgroundColor: Colors.primary },
        headerTintColor: Colors.light,
        headerTitle: (props) => <CustomHeader {...props} />, // Passed in here
        tabBarActiveTintColor: Colors.light,
        tabBarInactiveTintColor: Colors.lightInactive,
        tabBarActiveBackgroundColor: Colors.primary,
        tabBarInactiveBackgroundColor: Colors.primary,
      }}
      initialRouteName={'Visits'}
    >
      <Tab.Screen
        name='Visits'
        component={VisitsTab}
        options={{
          tabBarLabel: 'VISITS',
          tabBarIcon: ({ color, size }) => <FontAwesome name='street-view' color={color} size={size} />,
        }}
      />
      <Tab.Screen
        name='Chart'
        component={ChartTab}
        options={{
          tabBarLabel: 'CHARTS',
          tabBarIcon: ({ color, size }) => <FontAwesome name='id-badge' color={color} size={size} />,
        }}
      />
      <Tab.Screen
        name='Goals'
        component={GoalsTab}
        options={{
          tabBarLabel: 'EDIT GOALS',
          tabBarIcon: ({ color, size }) => <FontAwesome name='trophy' color={color} size={size} />,
        }}
      />
    </Tab.Navigator>
  );
};
```

Comment: Where are you updating state?  Can you create a minimal component which demonstrates this behavior?

Comment: I added that code above. This would be difficult to set up a minimal comp because of the way once is passed into the other -- see my comment about react losing focus on re-render on first character type. After much research, I found a way to resolve that part by using `onBlur` instead of `onChange` or `onChangeText`.

Comment: Are you sure the TextInput works fine? maybe console.log(text) in onBlur. Probably, it is an event and not text, maybe you got to use e.target.value

Comment: Well, I see the value type to the screen. How else would it be there? The note is being set otherwise I wouldn't see a value at all. I first see the placeholder text, and then when I type, it paints to the screen as expected.

Comment: You should include `props.client.id` in the dependency array `useEffect(() =>{  }, [note, props.client.id]);` and `if(!note)` check could stop it from clearing the value

Answer (score -1):

See here https://playcode.io/1106437, it works, but you have onBlur, you need to blur to trigger the action, maybe you need to use onChangeText insted.

Comment: Please read above. I cannot use onChangeText() in this case. I explained why. The issue is not getting the state to set - that IS happening. The issue is getting `useEffect` to fire after `note` has a value.